# Подключение к Oracle из Docker

Tags: python, oracle

Сервер Oracle крутится в докере

Вот образ

```
oracle/database              19.3.0-se2          16ac5716063a        3 hours ago         6.51GB
```

Так же есть клиентское приложение внутри другого образа докера.

```
oracle/instantclient         19                  a2a7021c1328        2 days ago          368MB
```

Там стоит python и  cx_Oracle. Приложение на базе Django будет делать запросы к серверу Oracle.

Собираю все вместе. Вот docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  oracle_server:
    image: oracle/database:19.3.0-se2
    ports:
      - 3333:1521
      - 3334:5500
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8989
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8989:8989
    links:
      - oracle_server
```

В setting.py в Django нужно указать данные для подключения к oracle:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'SID':'ORCLCDB',
    'USER': 'SYSTEM',
    'PASSWORD': 'xfZrvmBVyFs=1',
    'HOST': '172.17.0.1',
    'PORT': '3333',
 }
}
```

Не очень понимаю какие данные нужно вводить. HOST - ip-адрес докер-контейнера сервера?

В результате после docker-compose up имеем два контейнера

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                            NAMES
5a227f800775        search_books_web             "python3 manage.py r…"   49 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes             0.0.0.0:8989->8989/tcp                           search_books_web_1
9b65243c7516        oracle/database:19.3.0-se2   "/bin/sh -c 'exec $O…"   50 minutes ago      Up 4 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3333->1521/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3334->5500/tcp   search_books_oracle_server_1
```

командой

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 5a227f800775
```

узнаю ip контейнера с сервером oracle, но если его вставить в настройки Django то будет ошибка

```
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
```

PASSWORD ввел тот что выдал Oracle

```
ORACLE PASSWORD FOR SYS, SYSTEM AND PDBADMIN: xfZrvmBVyFs=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': '172.20.0.2:1521/ORCLCDB',
        'USER': 'SYSTEM',
        'PASSWORD': 'xfZrvmBVyFs=1',
        }
}
```

где 172.20.0.2 - это ip-адрес контейнера с сервером Oracle